# Is it correct the correspondence between probably/surely and should?

Tags: idioms, correspondence

Is it correct the correspondence between **probably/for sure** and **should**?

I mean, if the use of *should* is correct, besides to have the same meaning in phrases like:

He should be ok ←→ probably he is ok ←→ he is ok, for sure

**Context added**

When, for instance, I have no news from him for a long time and I wonder, or somebody ask me for him, then I answer with the previous phrases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different.

*The gunshot missed him. He should be okay except perhaps for shock.*

"should" indicates that the circumstances suggest he's okay.

---

*probably he is ok*

This is more tentative. It means we don't know. It could be that he is very capable and lucky so we ascribe a high probability to his being okay.

---

*he is ok, for sure*

He is definitely okay. Of course this could be used as a reassurance to someone where there is doubt in the mind of the speaker but they wish not to upset the other party.

---

**EDIT 1** in light of new context.

I wouldn't use any of those. Here are my suggestions:

> Somebody: How's John these days?
>
> You: As far as I know he's okay. I haven't heard from him for a long
> time.

This indicates that you don't know and may not be very interested in John's fate.

or

> Somebody: How's John these days?
>
> You: I expect he's okay. I haven't heard from him for a long
> time.

This indicates that you think he is probably okay because "no news is good news"

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/no-news-is-good-news

---

**EDIT 2** in response to comment by @Andrés Chandía

For me, the phrase, "he should be okay" is more likely to be used as a prediction, e.g.

> Somebody: Look, John is about to go into that cave! Will he be safe? There might be a bear in there.
>
> You: He should be okay. He is an expert cave explorer and will certainly be looking out for bears.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it made me realize that I should add some context, check the question again please.

Comment: Thanks again, I appreciate your suggestion, but is it wrong (not grammatically but in the use) if answer **He _should_ be ok**, in your last example? Could you understand from my answer that I'm intending to say something similar to "no news is good news". Probably a better answe is **He _should_ be doing ok**